# ColdFusion Enable RMI over SSL for Data Management Problems

Tags: java, flash, apache-flex, ssl, coldfusion

I am trying to Enable SSL connection between Flex/Flash Application and ColdFusion.
I followed the [directions outlined in the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=UseFlexDataService_09.html). However, when I get to:

> ***Configure Flex***
>
> Export the keystore to a certificate by using the keytool utility, with a command similar to the following:
>
> `keytool -export -v -alias FlexAssembler -keystore cf.keystore -rfc -file cf.cer`

I get a Java IOException:

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

The password is correct. The file is on a closed system, so nobody has tampered with the file. I assume I am supposed to import the certificated into:

```
/opt/coldfusion8/funtime/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

I have tried removing the "JRE cacerts" file, as suggested by another website, but that failed. Any ideas?

**Environment:**

- ColdFusion 8 Developer / Enterprise
- RedHat Linux Enterprise 6.0

Answer (score 0):

The KeyStore was tampered with, or the password isn't correct. No two ways about it.

The JRE cacerts file has nothing to do with a password problem on a different file.

Comment: The problem I am having is with importing the "cf.keystore" into the JRE cacerts file, using keytool -import -v -alias <alias> -file cf.cer -keystore <jre cacerts file>. I get the same error.  Do I need to import the cf.keystore file into jre cacerts file?